# Custom segmented control as search scope bar (iOS7)

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to get my app ready for iOS 7, but I'm having trouble with customising the scope bar in the search control. I've got a custom subclass of UISegmentedControl which looks how I want, and I'm using that as part of a custom table view elsewhere in the code. Does anyone know if I can replace the stock scope control for the search bar with my custom class, or am I stuck using the standard one?